# Not able to use Cassandra Interpreter in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: cassandra, apache-zeppelin

On executing cassandra code in Zeppelin notebook I get the following error on first run-

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.ClassPathBuilder$$anonfun$getClassPathFrom$3.apply(ClassPathBuilder.scala:147)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.ClassPathBuilder$$anonfun$getClassPathFrom$3.apply(ClassPathBuilder.scala:142)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:683)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:682)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.ClassPathBuilder$.getClassPathFrom(ClassPathBuilder.scala:142)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.ClassPathBuilder.addPathFrom(ClassPathBuilder.scala:68)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.ClassPathBuilder.addPathFromContextClassLoader(ClassPathBuilder.scala:73)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.support.ScalaCompiler.generateSettings(ScalaCompiler.scala:121)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.support.ScalaCompiler.<init>(ScalaCompiler.scala:59)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.support.ScalaCompiler$.create(ScalaCompiler.scala:42)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.createCompiler(TemplateEngine.scala:231)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compiler$lzycompute(TemplateEngine.scala:221)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compiler(TemplateEngine.scala:221)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:757)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoadEntry(TemplateEngine.scala:699)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.liftedTree1$1(TemplateEngine.scala:419)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:413)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:471)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.layout(TemplateEngine.scala:573)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$NoResultDisplay$.<init>(DisplaySystem.scala:369)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$NoResultDisplay$.<clinit>(DisplaySystem.scala)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.EnhancedSession.<init>(EnhancedSession.scala:40)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.InterpreterLogic.<init>(InterpreterLogic.scala:98)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.CassandraInterpreter.open(CassandraInterpreter.java:231)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:616)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And on the second run I get-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$NoResultDisplay$
    at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.EnhancedSession.<init>(EnhancedSession.scala:40)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.InterpreterLogic.<init>(InterpreterLogic.scala:98)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.CassandraInterpreter.open(CassandraInterpreter.java:231)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:616)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Apache Zeppelin version-0.8.2

Could it be because of JAR file versions inside \interpreter\cassandra ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please file an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN, can you also try Zeppelin 0.9-preview1 ? I suspect a generic problem in used library, but I need to investigate it further

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing similar issue and found a detailed analysis on why it is occuring . please follow the link to know root cause of the [issue](http://apache-zeppelin-users-incubating-mailing-list.75479.x6.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-Could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-zeppelin-cassandra-DisplaySystem-td6286.html)
And It was reported already at issues.apache.org [click here for report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4293)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for sharing a solution. It's best to include a summary of the solution in your answer in case the linked page goes offline at some point in the future.